# My jQuery Slider Controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

today ive made a slider, its code looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Tworzenie Kontrolek
    var html = "<ol id=\"controls\">";
    $('#slider ul li').each(function(i) {
        html += "<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\"><li id=\"" + (i+1) + "\">" + (i+1) + "</li></a>";
    });
    html += "</ol>";
    $('#slider').after(html);
    //Koniec tworzenia kontrolek

    //Ustawianie
    var width = $('#slider').width();
    var slides = $('#slider li').length;
    $('#slider ul').css("width", "" + (width*slides) + "");
    //Koniec ustawiania

        //Animowanie Slide'ow
        var cur = 1;
        var kontrolka = -1;
        var slider = setInterval(function() {
            if(cur < slides){   
                $('#slider ul').animate({left: "-" + (cur*width) + "px"},"linear");
                cur+=1;
                kontrolka+=1;
             }
             if(cur == slides){
                $('#slider ul').delay(3000).animate({left: "0px"},"linear");  
                cur=1;
                kontrolka=0;
             }

             //Kontrolki
            $('#controls li').removeClass("active");
            $('#controls li:contains(' + kontrolka + ')').addClass("active");
            //Koniec Kontrolek
        }, 3000);
        //Koniec Animowania Slidow

        //Klikanie Kontrolek
        $('#controls li').click(function() {
            var clicked = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#slider ul').animate({left: "-" + ((clicked-1)*width) + "px"},500,"linear"); 
            clearInterval(slider);
        });

    //Koniec klikania Kontrolek


});
```

Ive some problems with it, because it controls count from 1 to 4 leaves a 5 goes to 1 and on this 1 is image from slide number 5, i reallly dont know whats wrong, can someone help me?

P.S sorry for my bad english

ok jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Sck5w/ see how navigation is working: 1 2 3 4 good 5 missed and again 1

Comment: I'd recommend making a jsfiddle example -- we need more details. You might just need to set min=1 and max=5 but it is unclear by your code what is going on.

Comment: I just tried your code with jsfiddle and your controls seems to be ok, have a look http://jsfiddle.net/hU7zA/1/. I'd guess there is something wrong with your html, as @Cymen commented, you need to post more code for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your last slide set the var curl to -1.

```
if(cur == slides){
     $('#slider ul').animate({left: "0px"},"linear");  
     cur=-1; ==>>> 
     kontrolka=1;
}
```

Comment: @NiccoStaniewski have a look at this fiddle, I had to change several thigs to make it work, I left some comments. http://jsfiddle.net/vBvuw/2/

Answer (score 0):

**strong text**You almost had it with kontrolka, but then u used cur for control.

initialize cur to -1.

so, wherever you have

```
cur=1
```

it shoud be

```
cur=-1
```

It worked on jsfiddle!

Then:
instead of

```
$('#slider ul').animate({left: "-" + (cur*width) + "px"},"linear");
```

use

```
$('#slider ul').animate({left: "-" + ((cur+2)*width) + "px"},"linear");
```

And kontrolka shoud always be cur+1. So you can even omit it.

Comment: kontrolka should also stay as -1 or 0?

Comment: ok so it works now for controls, but images now are wrong. the second image is on 1 control, second on 3, third on 4, fourth on 5 and fifth on 1

Comment: ive found problem:if(cur == slides){
    
                $('#slider ul').delay(3000).animate({left: "0px"},"linear");  
                cur = 1;

             } its here so the cur = 1; works before it animate